# has boilerpipe any restriction at all?

Tags: java, boilerpipe

I want to use [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/archive/p/boilerpipe/) for scraping all acrticles (news) of a site for data mining purpose.
In demo page of boilerpipe is noted:

> Due to heavy use of this free service in the past, the number of
>   requests per user is limited

has boilerpipe library any restriction at all or this limitation is for demo page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are licensing terms that I have not seen the boilerpipe library should not have any such restriction.  The restriction you see is probably because the free site is a shared resource and unrestricted use will be abused by some (why use the library when there is a free service online that will do it for me?) and have a negative effect on those who are actually trying to use the demo site as intended.